# How to solve "[javac] error: invalid target release: 12.0.1" with command "ant run"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ant, build.xml

For error, check image

[image: click here for image]

I am attaching the compile code of my build.xml

```xml
<target name="compile" depends="init, clean">
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
    <echo message="making directory..."/>
    <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
    <echo message="classpath----: ${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="Compiling.."/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" debug="true" destdir="${test.dest}" srcdir="${test.src}" target="12.0.1" classpath="${test.classpath}">
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: What are the values of your `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only specify the Java specification version (or major version) in target of the `javac` task. So, instead of `target="12.0.1"`, it should be `target="12"`.